# Other div is not changing properties when hovering on a div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The div is not changing properties when I hover on the `<input>` of that div. It doesn't seem to work.

I want to hover over myclass div inputs and make myclass2 div visible.
How to do that ?

```css
.myclass #that:hover+.myclass2 #this {
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass" id="that">
  <input class="logout1" type="button" value="All" id="myBtn"></input>
  <input class="logout2" type="button" value="Section Wise" id="myBtn1"></input>
  <span class="first"></span>
  <span class="second"></span>
</div>
<div class="myclass2" id="this">
  <input class="logout3" type="button" value="Section1" id="myBtn2"></input>
  <input class="logout4" type="button" value="Section2" id="myBtn3"></input>
  <input class="logout5" type="button" value="Section3" id="myBtn4"></input>
  <input class="logout6" type="button" value="Section4" id="myBtn5"></input>
  <span class="third"></span>
  <span class="fourth"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: No need to use class in front of a unique ID

Comment: I think that CSS is always preferable over JavaScript. Well, this is not the case. Use JavaScript and you'll have an easier life

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. There is no closing tag for `<input>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.myclass2{
  display:none;
}

.myclass:hover+.myclass2{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass" id="that">
  <input class="logout1" type="button" value="All" id="myBtn">
  <input class="logout2" type="button" value="Section Wise" id="myBtn1"></input>
  <span class="first"></span>
  <span class="second"></span>
</div>
<div class="myclass2" id="this">
  <input class="logout3" type="button" value="Section1" id="myBtn2">
  <input class="logout4" type="button" value="Section2" id="myBtn3">
  <input class="logout5" type="button" value="Section3" id="myBtn4"
  <input class="logout6" type="button" value="Section4" id="myBtn5">
  <span class="third"></span>
  <span class="fourth"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot click the buttons though

Comment: I can click the buttons and from all the answers I see here this one seems to work the best.

Comment: You are copying his HTML with the same invalid closing `</input>` tag.

Comment: Thank you ! This worked fine. I think i messed up the order in the CSS file. Anyways Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

This works - you need position

HOWEVER you cannot click the new buttons - so see second example

```css
#this { position:absolute; width: 300px }

#that:hover + #this {
  right: 100px
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass" id="that">
  <input class="logout1" type="button" value="All" id="myBtn" />
  <input class="logout2" type="button" value="Section Wise" id="myBtn1" />
  <span class="first">First</span>
  <span class="second">Second</span>
</div>
<div class="myclass2" id="this">
  <input class="logout3" type="button" value="Section1" id="myBtn2" />
  <input class="logout4" type="button" value="Section2" id="myBtn3" />
  <input class="logout5" type="button" value="Section3" id="myBtn4" />
  <input class="logout6" type="button" value="Section4" id="myBtn5" />
  <span class="third">Third</span>
  <span class="fourth">Fourth</span>
</div>
```

I THINK you mean this:

```js
/* 
$("#myBtn").on("click",function() {
  $("#this").toggle()
})
*/

$("#myBtn").on("mouseenter",function() {
  $("#this").show();
})
$("#myBtn").on("mouseleave",function() {
  setTimeout(function() { $("#this").hide(); },3000);
})
```

```css
#this { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass" id="that">
  <input class="logout1" type="button" value="All" id="myBtn" />
  <input class="logout2" type="button" value="Section Wise" id="myBtn1" />
  <span class="first">First</span>
  <span class="second">Second</span>
</div>
<div class="myclass2" id="this">
  <input class="logout3" type="button" value="Section1" id="myBtn2" />
  <input class="logout4" type="button" value="Section2" id="myBtn3" />
  <input class="logout5" type="button" value="Section3" id="myBtn4" />
  <input class="logout6" type="button" value="Section4" id="myBtn5" />
  <span class="third">Third</span>
  <span class="fourth">Fourth</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: This isn't XHTML. But we've had this conversation before.

Comment: I very much prefer to write my markup the way the HTML specification is written by the browser vendors and not by the opinion of someone on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am betting you never use XML on any web page or you aren't properly serving it as XHTML. In any case, the closing slash is pure nonsense in HTML as the specification will tell you if you read it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wan't to make your `that` div visible when you hover `this`.
Then you can use visibile properties, can be managed with css or jquery method.

**Css method**

```
#that:hover + #this{
    visibility : visible;
}

#this{
    visibility : hidden;
}
```

**Jquery method**

Something like :

```
$('#this').hide();
$('#that').hover(function(event){
   $('#this').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the classes or the ids (or keep them if you need them for something else...) however here is an SCSS that can solve this issue for you:

Here, I removed the classes, but as I mentioned above, you can keep the classes and remove the Ids or keep them both :)

```
#this {
    display: none;
}

#that {
    &:hover {
        + {
            #this {
                display: block;
            }
        }
    }
}
```